# Dynamic LinkButton on GridView PagerTemplate not firing event

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, gridview, pagertemplate

I am doing a custom Pager Template for a gridview & trying to get something like:
< 1 2 3 4 >

I am having problems clicking on the numbers...

Inside the PagerTemplate i have a Placeholder named "phLinks" that is being filled on the DataBound Event like this:

```
protected void DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (grid.PageCount > 1)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < grid.PageCount; i++)
            {
                phLinks.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<li>"));
                LinkButton lb = new LinkButton { Text = (i + 1).ToString(), Enabled = grid.PageIndex != i, CommandArgument = i.ToString() };

                lb.Command += new CommandEventHandler(lb_Command);
                lb.CommandName = "Button";

                //lb.Click += new EventHandler(lb_Click);

                phLinks.Controls.Add(lb);
                phLinks.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</li>"));
            }
        }
    }
```

Please note that I have tried first the Click Event and then the Command Event, in both cases i get a post back but the event is not triggered...

What am i missing here?

Comment: Why are you using PageTemplate? If you set  PagerSettings-Mode="Numeric" property you'll get numeric pager.

Comment: I am using the PagerTemplate because i need to add other information to the Pager

Comment: lb.CommandName = "Button"; change this to lb.CommandName = "Page";

Comment: Had tried that before, didnt work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either bind your `GridView` on every postback :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       MyGridView.DataBind();

    }
```

OR turn off ViewState for your GridView::

`<asp:GridView ID="MyGridView" EnableViewState="false" ... />`.